# XSD byte[][] issue on Web Service

Tags: xsd, xml-serialization, wsdl, arrays

I'm trying to pass to my web service something like an array of byte array (byte[][]) to do that i created this xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="FileResponse"
targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/FileResponse.xsd"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/FileResponse.xsd"
xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/FileResponse.xsd"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>

 <xs:complexType name="FileResponse">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="SPResultItem" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="file" type="xs:unsignedByte" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Message" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:element name="FileResponse" type="FileResponse"/>
</xs:schema>
```

XSD tool generates this:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/FileResponse.xsd")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/FileResponse.xsd",     IsNullable=false)]
public partial class FileResponse {

private FileResponseSPResultStatus sPResultStatusField;

private sbyte[][] sPResultItemField;

private string messageField;

/// <remarks/>
public FileResponseSPResultStatus SPResultStatus {
    get {
        return this.sPResultStatusField;
    }
    set {
        this.sPResultStatusField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("file", typeof(sbyte), IsNullable=false)]
public sbyte[][] SPResultItem {
    get {
        return this.sPResultItemField;
    }
    set {
        this.sPResultItemField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
public string Message {
    get {
        return this.messageField;
    }
    set {
        this.messageField = value;
    }
}
```

}

As you can see, the conversion seems good: the xsd contains a "sbyte[][]" field... But when i call a method from this webservice (even if it doesn't use this class) it crashes without giving infos...

How can i create an XSD that receives a sbyte[][] or byte[][] and works? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Have you looked in Windows event log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="FileResponse"
targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/FileResponse.xsd"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/FileResponse.xsd"
xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/FileResponse.xsd"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>

<xs:complexType name="FileResponse">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="SPResultItem" type="fileList" maxOccurs="unbounded"> </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Message" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
```

```
<xs:complexType name ="fileList">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="file" type="xs:base64Binary"  ></xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="FileResponse" type="FileResponse"/>
```